# True(and easy) way to mask filenames in zip archive

Tags: php, zend-framework, zip, php-ziparchive

I generate Zip archive using ZipArchive lib in PHP. It works good, but if filename have disallowed symbols(for example '<' '>') archive has not this file.

I can just crop all dissallowed symbols.

I motiveless dislike crop. Any another way(may be mask but '\' and '^' doesnt work)?

Thanks.

Comment: `\ ` and `^` are acceptable ?

Comment: @CORRUPT `\`-yes for path in archive `^`-yes

Comment: @Tovr check bottom part of may answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try to use [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/preg-replace) for this:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain');

$file = '!@#$%^&*()ashdgf$%^&*(.pdf';

$file = preg_replace('/[^a-z\.\-\_]/i', '_', $file);

var_dump($file);
?>
```

Shows:

```
string(26) "__________ashdgf______.pdf"
```

---

If `\` and `^` are acceptable charaters, then use this:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain');

$file = 'folder\as!@#$%^&*()ashdgf$%^&*(.zip';

$file = preg_replace('/[^a-z\.\-\_\\\\^]/i', '_', $file);

var_dump($file);
?>
```

Shows:

```
string(35) "folder\as_____^____ashdgf__^___.zip"
```

You may add any other escaped symbols from whitelist to this expression.

Comment: nice way but why you replace `_` for `_` ?=)

Comment: I'm not. Everything in `[^` and `]` are not replaced. It is a whitelist.