# PHP Rename and illegal filename

Tags: php

I have a strange problem with renaming an existing file:

I have on my server a series of html files that need to be selected via a file selection dialog and then renamed.

The form that opens the dialog is called via JavaScript and correctly opens the dialog, allows a file to be selected, and renames it, right up until I come across a file with some (presumably) illegal characters in it. At this point I get a file not found error.

The source and destination for the rename are the same, it is only the filename that needs to be changed.

My code, which works on other files is as follows (with variables renamed for some clarity):

```
$dest_path = realpath(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))) . $miDestination ;
$targefile = $dest_path  .  basename( $_FILES["thesrcfile"]["name"]);
$newName = $dest_path . $anewname . ".html";
rename($targefile,$newName);
```

As mentioned this works fine until I reach a file with a name such as:

```
These are "very" strangely-named file's!.html
```

From this I get a file not found error. All permissions are correct and this code has been working fine with more sensibly named files. By the way, I have no control over the names of the files and they can quite literally contain any characters.

Can anyone suggest a way to get the rename function to recognise these files as existing, and to rename them accordingly?

many thanks

Max

Comment: Generate random names, don't accept the original name ever.

Comment: Check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16786641/trueand-easy-way-to-mask-filenames-in-zip-archive/16786701#16786701).

Comment: @zerkms: The original files are copied to their location via another process - I have no control over the names until they reach the desired folder, at which point I want to rename them.

Comment: @CORRUPT: how exactly does that code help me to rename the file?

Comment: @MaxVK you may try to use it to transform filenames to filesystem compatible names. You may apply it to `$anewname` before `$newName = $dest_path . $anewname . ".html";`, for example.

Comment: Sorry, perhaps I need another coffee, but surely if I change the name which is passed to rename, it wont be able to find the file, since that has not yet been renamed?

Comment: You are changing new name, not old name. File would be rename to newname which should be compatible.

Comment: The new name works fine, it the old name that is the problem! Because of the characters in it, the PHP rename function cannot find the file, in fact file_exists cant find the file either (Yes, it does exist!). This is the problem - the filename prevents PHP from finding it, presumably because of the characters in the name.

Answer (score 0):

`trim()` and `str_replace()` all illegals char into $anewname var

Comment: As I mentioned in another comment, surely changing the string is irrelevant since the string represents the file as it exists before renaming - changing the string will fail to find the file?

Comment: So it's your $_FILES["thesrcfile"]["name"] than PHP don't find ?

Comment: Yes. The file exists (with no intervention from me) already, and I'm trying to rename it in place, however, the filename itself is not being recognised because of the characters in it. I can sanitize the string, but that simply means that it will not then match the file itself, so file not found will actually be correct.

Comment: Can you see the name of file when is already uploaded ? To see the difference ? for exemple : These%20are%20%22very%22%20strangely%2Dnamed%20file%27s%21.html

Comment: The file is seen and selected in a file dialog, fired from a form. I can read and print the filename to the console but PHP fails to find it when I try to perform any action on it. The filename as seen is exactly as it should be, PHP just cant find it.